# How to have UDP Server and Client simultaneously listening for incoming and outgoing packets

Tags: java, multithreading, udp

I'm trying to implement a simple UDP connection in Java and I want both Client and Server to be both listening for incoming messages and be ready to send messages at the same time.

At the moment, the program is such that the server starts out listening for incoming packets so the client send the first message.

I'd really like to know of a simple way to implement this if possible.

Here's the code for the Client:

```
class EchoClient 
{
    public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception 
    {
        System.out.println("\nWelcome to UDP Client");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
        socket.setSoTimeout(120000);

        while (true)
        {
            //Send
            System.out.print("\nEnter message: ");
            String msg = sc.nextLine();         
            byte[] buffer = msg.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket packetS = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length,InetAddress.getByName(args[0]),1500);
            socket.send( packetS );
            
            //Receive
            DatagramPacket packetR = new DatagramPacket(new byte[512],512);
            socket.receive( packetR );
            System.out.println( "Alice at: "+new Date()+" "+packetR.getAddress()+":"+packetR.getPort()+"\nSays: "+new String(packetR.getData(),0,packetR.getLength()) );
        }
    }
}
```

And the code for the Server:

```
class EchoServer 
{
    public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception 
    {
        System.out.println("\nWelcome to UDP Server");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(1500);
    
        //Message loop
        while ( true ) 
        {   
            //Receiving
            DatagramPacket packetR = new DatagramPacket(new byte[512],512);
            socket.receive( packetR );
            System.out.println("Bob at: "+new Date()+" "+packetR.getAddress()+":"+packetR.getPort()+"\nSays: "+new String(packetR.getData(),0,packetR.getLength()) );
    
            //Send
            System.out.print("\nEnter message: ");
            String msg = sc.nextLine();
            byte[] buffer = msg.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket packetS = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length,packetU.getAddress(),packetU.getPort());
            socket.send( packetS );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Re, "ready to send messages..." sounds,... odd. Are you talking about _two_ threads, one of which waits to receive messages, while the other does various things such as, send messages? or do you think you need _three_ threads, where one awaits input, one does other stuff, and the third one waits for either of the other two to _tell it_ to send a message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello an eay way for doing that is to have mutltiple thread launched in the main.

```java
class EchoServerClient 
{
    public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception 
    {
        new Thread(() -> {
            EchoServer.main(args) //You can also rename main by another name
        }).start();
        new Thread(() -> {
            EchoClient.main(args) //You can also rename main by another name
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: So. I'll have to create another class that calls the mains of both Server and Client? 

If that's the case, my Server and Client are in different directories. Any idea how I can access them both from this third class?

Comment: Directories or project ?
And can you put them in the same project ?

Comment: I'm doing it very simply. I put both Server and Client .java files in different folders and compiled and ran them on two separate cmd terminals. Not very familiar with Java, to be frank.

Comment: OK, two solutions, you put the two class in the class EchoServerClient. Or you add the third class in a différent file and you import them. During the compilation you will have too compile  the 3 class in the same time